# strange error in CHROME when trying to load XML with Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, google-chrome

Hi, I'm new to html5 and jquery development. I have a problem with loading XML using jQuery apparently only on Chrome. My site is:

> http://shaharmesh.hostingsiteforfree.com/

As you can see that the **Portfolio Section** is working fine with all browsers *except* Chrome. When I open Chrome JavaScript console, I see this error:

> event_bindings: 232
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) ...

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function()  
    {  
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../Assets/protfolio.xml",
            dataType: "XML",
            success: xmlParser
         });
    });
```

***xmlParser.js** is the jQuery script that loads the XML*

Any help will be  appreciated.

Comment: Did you try opening the console on FF?

Comment: Firebug is awesome, but the default dev tools are preety good too

Comment: Are you sure it's spelt `Protfolio` and not `Portfolio` (it was there, both on your site and here, so I couldn't assume it to be a typo...)

Comment: in FF its working no problems, allso in internet explorer.

Comment: I checked right now too... strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `sandbox` attribute on the iframe, causing all restrictions to apply except the ones you set. You didn't set `allow-same-origin`, so the origin was treated unique and you were experiencing a cross domain error.

You can add `allow-same-origin` to the attribute value to bring it back to its normal state with respect to the origin.

[See the specification:](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox)

> When the attribute is set, the content is treated as being from a unique origin ...